# Spring Roo errors in Roo_Service_Impl.aj

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, spring-roo, aspectj-maven-plugin

In the domain model, Category that has a ManyToOne relation with Tag entity, and Tag has ManyToOne with OfferingDetail.
I'm getting these errors in the TagServiceImpl_Roo_Service_Impl.aj file:

```
The method setTag(null) is undefined for the type OfferingDetail
```

Similar errors with a couple of other entities.
The setter/getter is .aj source file. Surprisingly, the error shows up only for the first setTag below, not the second! Why does this error occur, and how do I resolve this? I've tried reindex JDT weaving.

> ```
> @Transactional
> public void TagServiceImpl.delete(Tag tag) {
>     // Clear bidirectional many-to-one child relationship with Category
>     if (tag.getCategory() != null) {
>         tag.getCategory().getTags().remove(tag);
>     }
>
>     // Clear bidirectional one-to-many parent relationship with OfferingDetail
>     for (OfferingDetail item : tag.getOurPlay()) {
>         item.setTag(null);
>     }
>
>     // Clear bidirectional one-to-many parent relationship with UseCase
>     for (UseCase item : tag.getUseCases()) {
>         item.setTag(null);
>     }
>
>     getTagRepository().delete(tag);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The error was because I'd changed a property name in the entity, but Roo shell apparently did not pick up the change and modify other files.